# Bootstrap buttons have strange artifact on right edge

Tags: html, button, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, safari

I am using the excellent [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework on  my page and have come across a strange issue where button elements have a line on the right edge. This is only happening in Safari (Chrome, Mobile Safari and FF seem to work fine). How can I fix this?

[image]

Relevant code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Mac App Coming Soon</a>
```

Live Example: [Hourly News Website](http://hourlynewsapp.com)

Comment: have you modified the btn classes at all ? or this a clean install of twitter bootstrap ? It kind of looks like the buttons width is 1px too long and are repeating.

Comment: I only changed the color of these buttons. It happens on the default bootstrap page with Safari too. It seems to be a bug with the corner radius, not the right edge.

Comment: I noticed it on a static navbar (not fixed-top). In my case it is fine at some widths, and bad at others (just like above image). This is a stock download from a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Have you fixed it? can't see any problem

Comment: I haven't touched the code from this old question. Safari may have changed something though... It appears to happen less frequently now

Comment: But it does still happen: http://cloud.coneybeare.net/MzBq